# Como puedo eliminar varios registros de diferentes tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas que almacenan un dato idéntico, la primera tabla es de Coches en donde almaceno su idCoche como PK, en la siguiente tengo la tabla Compra en donde tiene el idCoche como FK y el otro que seria Venta que es el mismo caso que la tabla Compra.
Lo que deseó es eliminar ese registro de esas 3 tablas.
El trabajo es en SQL.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que has intentado hasta el momento? Recuerda que este sitio no es un repositorio de código: muestra tus intentos y los problemas que tuviste. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues sí. Puedes hacer 3 `DELETE` en el orden apropiado, pues debes recordar que la FK no te permitirá borrar un registro de `Coches` hasta que no hayas eliminados los registros vinculados en las tablas que lo usen de clave ajena.

Y la opción que me parece mejor, que sería redefinir las FK de las tablas, que se habrán creado así:

```
CREATE TABLE Coches(
  idCoche int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  );
CREATE TABLE Compra(
  idCompra int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  idCoche int,
  FOREIGN KEY(idCoche) REFERENCES Coches(idCoche)
  );
CREATE TABLE Venta(
  idVenta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  idCoche int,
  FOREIGN KEY(idCoche) REFERENCES Coches(idCoche)
  );
```

Y sustituirlas por:

```
ALTER TABLE Compra
  DROP FOREIGN KEY Compra_ibfk_1;

ALTER TABLE Compra 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(idCoche) 
  REFERENCES Coches(idCoche) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Venta
  DROP FOREIGN KEY Venta_ibfk_1;

ALTER TABLE Venta 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(idCoche) 
  REFERENCES Coches(idCoche) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

De esta forma, al ejecutar:

```
DELETE FROM Coches WHERE idCoche=1;
```

Se eliminarán todos los registros en cascada con una única instrucción.

Puedes comprobarlo con un simple:

```
INSERT INTO Coches (idCoche) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO Compra (idCoche) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Venta (idCoche) VALUES (1);
```

Con un `SHOW CREATE TABLE Venta;` podrás ver el nombre que se les ha dado a las FK: `Compra_ibfk_1` y `Venta_ibfk_1`.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y recuerda poner tus intentos en la pregunta.

Comment: pero este usuario no ha mostrado un ejemplo mínimo, porque le contestaste? @DavidJP

Comment: Porque el OP es nuevo y me gustó la pregunta: nunca había redefinido una FK, así que me pareció divertido intentarlo :)

Comment: vale amigo muchas gracias por la aclaración entonces si es nuevo si podemos responderle preguntas de este tipo? :)

Comment: A ver, la idea es que la gente aprenda a preguntar y se esfuercen un mínimo, no que nos tiren ahí la tarea para que se la hagamos... Pero, en este caso, la vi bien redactada y me pareció interesante. Aún así, seguro que alguien me regaña :D Pero creo que a este OP le he ayudado a pescar, no le he dado peces

Comment: vale muchas gracias y como te regañan te meten en el chat de SOes ?

Comment: Al menos a mí nunca me han hecho eso... Simplemente te dejan un comentario diciéndote que no deberías haber respondido o te votan negativo... La gente aquí es maja, todos buscamos lo mismo: que el sitio sea útil y responder a preguntas mal planteadas no ayudará a nadie, por esos  a veces son un poco estrictos, pero las intenciones son buenas... :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135940/discussion-between-javier-g-raya-and-david-jp).

Comment: @DavidJP primeramente muchas gracias por la ayuda, y también pedir perdón si es que le cause algún inconveniente al responderme, soy nuevo en todo esto de la programación y pues me fue de gran ayuda :P

Comment: @DavidJP si desea que elimine la pregunta para que no tenga ningún tipo de problema, con mucho gusto la realizaré :P

Comment: @user281540 Jajajaja, no te preocupes, al contrario. Tú sigue preguntando todo lo que necesites, pero intenta siempre algo y ya te iremos orientando si tienes que completar alguna pregunta. Bienvenido a [so] :)

Comment: @DavidJP Muchas gracias, nuevamente :P